# Global variable not changing

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a code sort of like this, with this being simplified for your time. Basically I will have multiple threads that may start while the other is still in progress, and I want the new process to kill the old one, yet in the code below **loop()** doesn't want to die, and I don't know why. Also is there any better way to do this?

Please assume another program imports this module and executes automation.loopwrapperwrapper(0,255) and automation.loopwrapperwrapper(0,255) again before the first thread ends.

```
import threading
import time

die=0
value=0

def loop(valuefrom, valueto)
    global value
    global die
    die=0
    while value<>valueto:
        if die==1:
            return value
        if value>valueto:
            value -= 1

        else:
            value += 1
            time.sleep(1)
    return value

def loopwrapper(valuefrom, valueto)
    global die
    die=1
    value=loop(valuefrom, valueto)
    return value

def loopwrapperwrapper(valuefrom,valueto)
    t = threading.Thread(target=loopwrapper, args=(valuefrom,valueto))
    t.start()
```

If I had wrongly simplified this and the code does work, here is the actual code I'm working with. http://pastebin.com/SCR6pUwi

I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Does python have a `<>` operator?

Comment: `if die==1` will never be true, by the way

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, and yes I should use != instead, but it's still supported.

Comment: Why cant die==1 ?
What if when a new thread is started and it sets die to 1

Comment: You import some modules, set some variables, and define some functions. Nothing is actually happening.

Comment: Well because these are the only things I find that are not working.

Comment: There's only one thread that I see here. You set die to 0 before the loop, and it never changes within that function. Your questions should include a [mcve] of the problem, not disconnected extracts from a larger program

Comment: Sorry, my bad, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below command:

Instead of die==1, use die=='1'or"1", or you can use -eq instead of == --> this may work